# Write holomorphic function $f$ globally as $(z-z_0)^{\text{ord}_{z_0}(f)} g(z)$ if $\text{ord}_{z_{0}(f)} < + \infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the following let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open, $f \in \mathrm {H}(U)$ holomorphic and we define $\text{ord}_{z_{0}}(f)$ as the *order of vanishing* of $f$ at $z_{0} \in U.$

In my complex analysis lecture we proved the following result:

If $\text{ord}_{z_{0}}(f) < +\infty,$ then there exists a holomorphic function $g \in \mathrm{H}(U)$ such that $g(z_{0})\not = 0$ and for all $r>0$ with $D_{r}(z_{0}) \subseteq U$ we have $$f(z)=(z-z_{0})^{\text{ord}_{z_{0}}(f)}g(z) \tag{1}$$for all $z \in D_{r}(z_{0}).$

Now I was wondering if we could get a similar global picture under the assumption that $U$ is simply connected, i.e. if $U$ were simply connected, could we find a similar $g \in \mathrm{H}(U)$ with $g(z_{0}) \not = 0$ such that (1) holds for every $z \in U$? Does anyone know whether this is even true (so whether I should continue trying to prove this, for me it didn't work as of now...) or does anyone have some kind of counter-example to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have the result for $D_r(z_0)$, then outside the disk you can simply take $g(z) = f(z)/(z-z_0)^{\text{ord}_{z_0}(f)}$. This is holomorphic since $z\neq z_0$ and $f$ is holomorphic. There's no need for simply connectedness.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would actually work in the most general sense. Consider two disjoint discs $D_1(0), D_1(5)$ and define $f$ on $D_1(0)$ by $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z-5}$ and on $D_1(5)$ by $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-1}$. In this case i think we can't really write $f(z) = (z-1)g(z)$ globally.

Comment: I think your $f$ does not even have a zero and I don't see why you cannot write $f$ in that way. Define $g(z) = \frac{1}{z-5}$ on $D_1(0)$ and $\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$ on $D_1(5)$.

Comment: Oh you're right, I got a bit confused there. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are asking about -- if you mean that your expansion is valid for all z in the domain U then I think the following might be a counterexample:

consider $f(z)=z/(1-z)$ defined on $B_1(i)\cup B_1(0)$, which is simply connected, then the expansion of $f$ is $\sum^\infty_{n=1}z^n$ inside the region $B_1(0)$ (and this is unique) but the expansion is $\sum^{-\infty}_{n=0}z^n$ on $\overline{B}_1(0)^c\cap B_1(i)$ (it cannot be $\sum^\infty_{n=1}z^n$ on this region since this expansion doesn't converge here).

Comment: As I commented above, still there is an analytic function $g$ satisfying the equality on the whole domain, although it may not be given by power series at $z_0$.